# Flutter ios app lost connection on calling ImagePicker.getImage() with no error

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

This is the gif showing app crashed
https://media.giphy.com/media/Qm9PALMAtAw2W4AUzf/giphy.gif

```
onPressed: () => _pickImage(),
```

```
Future _pickImage() async {
    image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
}
```

There's no error message or anything, just lost connection to device

[image]

This lost connection behavior also happend when calling `Navigator.pop()` to close dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below line in Info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can i get permission to pick image?</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can i get permission to pick image?</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can i get permission to pick image?</string>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I somehow read past it on the package installation

Comment: Happens sometimes